# Compiler optimization when chaining operators

Tags: c++, optimization, operator-overloading

I overloaded the arithmetic/assignment operators on `std::vector` in order to be able to do some basic linear algebra operations. However, I'm having some performance trouble when chaining those operations.

Here's the content of my `main.h`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<float> vec;

inline vec& operator+=(vec& lhs, const vec& rhs) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i) {
        lhs[i] += rhs[i];
    }
    return lhs;
}

inline vec operator*(float lhs, vec rhs) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i) {
        rhs[i] *= lhs;
    }
    return rhs;
}
```

Content of `main1.cpp`:

```
#include "main.h"

// gcc 4.9.2 (-O3): 0m5.965s
int main(int, char**) {
    float x = rand();
    vec v1(1000);
    vec v2(1000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
        v1[i] = rand();
        v2[i] = rand();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        v1 += x * v2;

        // same as:
        //vec y = x * v2;
        //v1 += y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Content of `main2.cpp`:

```
#include "main.h"

// gcc 4.9.2 (-O3): 0m2.400s
int main(int, char**) {
    // same stuff

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < v1.size(); ++j) {
            v1[j] += x * v2[j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second program runs much faster than the first. I do understand why this is the case: instead of just one loop, the first program does two loops, and it allocates a temporary vector.

But this is the kind of thing I'd expect the compiler to see and optimize. Or am I doing something wrong?

I don't recall having this problem with linear algebra libraries (e.g. Armadillo). How do they tackle this problem? Does this involve some complicated template programming, or is there some simple way to help the compiler optimize this?

Comment: Armadillo makes heavy use of expression templates.

Comment: My measurements are 1 and 0.85

Comment: Expression templates almost certainly explain the difference. GMP uses similar approaches to minimize unnecessary work; the operators return objects that describe the logical operation w/o performing work; if a subsequent operation can be combined in a more efficient way, it does so. It's only on assignment to a concrete type that the expression is resolved/computed (through implicit cast), which can reduce the work (for example, `(a * b) & 1` might be expensive to compute for 1000+ bit `a`/`b`, but expression templates could distribute the `& 1` so the multiplication is on one bit values.

Answer (score 1):

There were some super ugly template meta-programming solutions to that problem.  But then the standards committee invented the combination of rvalue references and move semantics.  Look those up and find many examples of the solution without the absurd levels of meta programming.

Comment: I don't see any useful application of move semantics in the code of the question.

Comment: @Dieter, I misunderstood a detail in the posted code.  I think you are correct.  It takes very tricky template metaprogramming to avoid allocating space for the temporary to hold the result of `operator*()`.  The more common case where C++11 features make that easy doesn't quite fit.